# ES6 not getting compiled. I am using Babel with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use babel with webpack so that my ES6 code is converted to vanilla javascript. I am not receiving any errors but I don't think my ES6 is getting converted to vanilla Javascript. I am using below packages for webpack and babel-

```
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"webpack": "^4.39.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file -:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
 entry: './src/index.js',
 output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
     filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 mode: 'development',
 module: {
     rules: [
         {
             test: '/\.js$/',
             loader: 'babel-loader',
             exclude: '/node_modules/'
         }
     ]
 }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Also in my .babelrc file I have written -:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

The bundle.js is still having same code -:

```
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("const sum = __webpack_require__(/*! ./sum */ \"./src/sum.js\");\r\n\r\nconst total = sum(10, 4);\r\n\r\nlet array = [1,2,3];\r\n\r\nArray.from(array).forEach(($item) => {\r\n console.log($item);\r\n})\r\n\r\nconsole.log(total);\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/index.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/sum.js":
/*!********************!*\
  !*** ./src/sum.js ***!
  \********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("const sum = (a, b) => a + b;\r\n\r\nmodule.exports = sum;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/sum.js?");

/***/ })
```

This code is still having const and arrow functions.
So there is no error but still code is not getting compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `targets` option in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "targets": "last 1 version, IE >= 11"
}
```

Alternatively (and this is now the recommended way), introduce this into your project's `package.json`

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "IE >= 11"
]
```